# asp.net find datatable item

Tags: datatable

hi i have a datatable with 2 columns one for id(unique) and another for "description". now i have a dropdownlist with "description" from the same datatable mentioned above. when users selects a particular item from description, i need to pick the id corresponding to the selected value. what is the easiest way to achieve this, should i use a foreach or datatable find method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the Dropdownlist's [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) to the Description and its [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) to the ID.

```
MyDropDownList.DataSource = MyDataTable
MyDropDownList.DataTextField = "Description"
MyDropDownList.DataValueField = "ID"
MyDropDownList.DataBind()
```

Then you can get the ID via `MyDropDownList.SelectedValue`.

Comment: @Sam:  i have nowhere mentioned `selecteditem` but `SelectedValue`. You should ensure to pupulate your dropdownlist only if `Not Page.IsPostBack`, otherwise your selection gets lost.

Comment: i have to select the value from first drop down and load the values in second dropdown list box.

Comment: @sam: Then you have to handle the SelectedIndexChanged event from first dropdown and bind second DDL to first' SelectedValue property. It would be a  lot easier to help if you'd provided some source code.

Comment: I fixed that. sorry, dropdown's autopostback was set to false. i didnt check that. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you might want to give some more information- what programming language you're using (I'm assuming C#)
now, regarding what you've described, you probably want to use the datatable's find method, or, preferrably- use LINQ on the datatable.

```
table.First(x=> x.description == desc).Id;
```

(note that this code assumes that an element with a matching description exists. If such an element may not exist- use FirstOrDefault and check the return result for null value).
good luck.

Comment: actually, Tim's answer is probably even better in your case.

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of this can be found here

http://forums.asp.net/p/1590755/4029475.aspx

Using the answer provided above yoyuu would then use dropdownlist.selecteditem.value, hope this helps.